# CSS3: Ubicar H3 y el parrafo dentro de un GRID

Tags: css, css3, css-grid-layout

Necesito ubicar el texto que está encuadrado en amarillo, dentro de la foto, o sea del contenedor-2. A pesar que pongo:

```
.container-2 h3{
        grid-column: 2 / 3;
        grid-row: 2;
    }
```

> El h3 ni el parrafo se mueven de lugar para dentro del contenedor-2.
>   ¿Cómo podría arreglarlo?.

Son 4 grillas iguales. Adjunto el ejemplo de la primera.

```css
body{
  background-color: #e6e6ed;
 }


 *{box-sizing: border-box}

 .main{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:42px 320px 37px 320px 83px;
  grid-template-rows: 134px 319px 126px 486px 57px;
 }  

 .main{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 802px;
 }
 
 .container-1{
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 2 / 5;
 }

 .container-2{
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
 }

 .container-3{
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 4 / 5;
 }

 .container-4{
  grid-row: 3;
  grid-column: 2 / 5;
 }

 .container-5{
  grid-row: 4;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  background-color: #fff;
 }
 
 .container-6{
  grid-row: 4;
  grid-column: 4 / 5;
  background-color: #fff;
 }

 
 a{
  text-decoration: none;
 }

 .foto{
   height: 590px;
    width: 970px;
 }

 .container-2 h3 p{
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 2;
 }
```

```html
<main class="main">
   <div class="container-1"><h2 class="titulo">Destacadas de la semana</h2></div>
      
   <section class="container-2">
     <img class=foto src="https://s13.postimg.org/r5md4u6kn/Screenshot-2018-1-2_Test.png">
     <h3>Show</h3>
     <p><span class="descripcion">#FuerzaNoha:<br/> famosos preocupados<br/>por el hijo mayor de<br/>Luisana</span></p>
   </section>
  </main>
```

Comment: Buenas @MariaInesMcLoughlin, el código lo deberías añadir en la pregunta y no poniendo un enlace, ya que si se pierde el enlace la pregunta ya no valdría como válida.

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta, no lo pongas como comentario. Por cierto, recuerda que los atributos `grid-*` están en estado [de borrador, o `CR` (Candidate Recommendation)](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#propdef-grid). No deberías usarlas en producción.

Comment: Cual es el texto en amarillo?

Answer (score -1):

te dejo un enlace [**aquí**](https://jsfiddle.net/q837nurx/7/) con una posible solución en fiddle

Saludos